# Deserializing JSON data (array) to C# using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Hey and thanks in advance!

I'm trying to deserialize a webAPI Json but struggling on getting the array (list?)

I have this Json from webAPI which i can't edit.

```
{
  "Id": "83eb701d-c280-4d39-8333-29e574898b07",
  "UserName": "silver",
  "Joined": "2015-05-14T18:42:55.14",
  "UserListedBookDtos": [
    {
      "ISBN": "9780553897845",
      "Title": "A Game of Thrones",
      "Description": "A NEW ORIGINAL SERIES.....",
      "Length": 720,
      "Author": "George R.R. Martin",
      "Status": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i am trying to deserialize it with this:

```
        public static async Task RunAsyncGetUserBooks()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44300/");
                var response = await client.GetAsync("api/users/"+Login.UsName+"");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserBooksResponse>();
                    MessageBox.Show(result.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong!");
                }
            }
        }
```

For classes i'm using these two:

```
        public class UserListedBookDtos
        {

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ISBN")]
            public int ISBN { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Title")]
            public string Title { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Description")]
            public string Description { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Length")]
            public int Length { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Author")]
            public string Author { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Status")]
            public int Status { get; set; }

        }

        public class UserBooksResponse
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserName")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Joined")]
            public string Joined { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserListedBookDtos")]
            public IList<UserListedBookDtos> UserListedBookDtos { get; set; }

        }
```

However i can not seem to get any information from server what so ever while having List part of UserBooksResponse included. However, if i comment that part out:

```
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserListedBookDtos")]
        public IList<UserListedBookDtos> UserListedBookDtos { get; set; }
```

I receive Id, UserName and Joined without any problems. I'm quite new to C# and can't seem to figure out what's causing this. I would highly appreciate anyone who could either let me know why it isn't retrieving anything from the server while the list is included, or what should i do in order to get the data from the list as well.

**UPDATE**

I found the answer for my first question, as is why i retrieved no information at all. It was caused because my ISBN was int and not a string, as it needed to be. Thanks for the debugger tip!

Comment: Did you try with List<...>, instead of IList<...> ?

Comment: Also try commenting out each of your properties of your UserListedBookDtos class, to see if the problem is indeed with the array or just in one property of the class in the array

Comment: try to use the debugger and step into your code step by step and check the values

Comment: Yes i did, unfortunately the results were the same. I'm problably wrong, but on my knowledge, the List <> can't include "aray"'s which i think my json UserListedBookDtos part is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're mapping the `ISBN` property as `int`, but the value 9780553897845 is much too large for a 32-bit integer. It could fit in a `long` (`Int64`), but you should probably map it as a `string` instead, because it's not really a number (it's an identifier that just happens to be made only of digits).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, and indeed, that was the culprit for my first problem, I managed to fix it seconds before. 

My second wall is still up though, Dont seem to find the way to save the info from the array itself. I think its due to the fact that i'm not saving the  infor properly in

var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserBooksResponse>();

Or the info is not retrieved at all.

Comment: @svanamet, I don't understand what you mean. I tried to deserialize your JSON sample using your classes (with the fix on ISBN) and it works fine. What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the info from the List<UserListedBookDtos>, as Title, Decription, length,Author and Status into Datagridview but the fields show up empty. I think i must be either deserialize it wrong or my datagridview is set up badly.

Comment: @svanamet, a quick test in LinqPad shows that the data is correctly deserialized, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you and an apology for using your time! Now i know that i need to look from somewhere else.